# SQL Server 2005 terminating connections after 30 sec

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, oracle-sqldeveloper

We moved our SQL Server 2005 database to a new physical server, and since then it has been terminating any connection that persist for 30 seconds.

We are experiencing this in Oracle SQL developer and when connecting from python using pyodbc
Everything worked perfectly before, and now python returns this error after 30 seconds:

('08S01', '[08S01] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Read from the server failed (20004) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all what you need is profile the sql server to see if any activity is happening. Look for slow running queries, CPU and memory bottlenecks.

Also you can include the timeout in the querystring like this: 
"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connection Timeout=30"; 
and extend that number if you want.

But remember "timeout" doesn't means time connection, this is just the time to wait while trying to establish a connection before terminating.

I think this problem is more about database performance or maybe a network issue.

Comment: network issue.  never figured it out, but it doesn't appear to be the database.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check your remote query timeout? It should default to 600, but maybe it's set to 30? [Info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189040%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)